# Why the difference between a loop and a single run

Tags: ruby, loops

The loop prints 23401, but the last line does not print:

```
[2,3,4,0,1].each do |value|
    print value if value==2...value==2
end

print true if 3==2...3==2
```

I wonder what the problem is

I've tried a lot of loops, and I've found that conditions are always true once they're true

Answer (score 2):

This `value==2...value==2` might look like a standard `Range`; however the syntax of `if (condition)...(condition)` is actually a control expression called a [Flip-Flop](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-Flip-Flop).

> The form of the flip-flop is an expression that indicates when the flip-flop turns on, `..` (or `...`), then an expression that indicates when the flip-flop will turn off. While the flip-flop is on it will continue to evaluate to `true`, and `false` when off.

There are 2 forms 2 dots (`..`) and 3 dots (`...`).

- 2 dots (`..`) means: "...the off condition is evaluated when the on condition changes."; and
- 3 dots (`...`) means: "...the off condition is evaluated on the following iterations"

## 2 dots form (`..`) of the flip-flop

```
[2, 3, 4, 0, 1].each do |value|
    print value if (value == 2)..(value == 2)
end
# 2
```

Because the first iteration turns on the flip-flop for only this iteration e.g. left hand side (on) `2 == 2` and the right hand side (off) `2 == 2` so it turns on, evaluates, and turns off in the same iteration.

## 3 dots form (`...`) of the flip-flop as in your example

```
[2, 3, 4, 0, 1].each do |value|
    print value if (value == 2)...(value == 2)
end
# 23401
```

Because the first iteration turns on the flip-flop e.g. left hand side (on) `2 == 2` but the right hand side (off) `value == 2` is not evaluated until the following iterations and since no other elements in the array satisfy `value == 2` it does not turn off.

If there were another element that satisfied the off condition in your array:

```
[2, 3, 4, 2, 0, 1].each {|value| print(value) if (value == 2)...(value == 2) } 
# 2342
```

## Additional

> ...but the last line does not print:

Your last line does not print because the left hand side (`3 == 2`) is false so the flip-flop does not turn on (Additionally using a flip-flop outside of a loop makes no real sense).